# Using material ui and Tailwind css in react projects

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

Is it okay to use tailwind css and material ui in a react project? do classes conflict?

Comment: Yes, both work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use both, there won't be conflict but there will be a lot of mess so keep that thing in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI is supporting tailwind now, you can check the docs :  https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css